# nginx proxy cache path - logic?

Tags: nginx

I understand how to use levels in proxy_cache_path, 1 or 1:2, or 1:1:2, etc ... but I don't undestand the LOGIC of levels ... ? I'm about to cache around ~ 10 GB of files, currently I've set:

```
proxy_cache_path /usr/local/nginx-cache-server/proxy-cache levels=1 keys_zone=svdld:100m inactive=1d max_size=100G;
```

Could someone please explain the logic of levels here ? What exactly are them ? How could them affect me if I use 1 or 1:1 or 1:2, etc ... ?

```
root@test:/usr/local/nginx-cache-server/proxy-cache# ls
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
root@test:/usr/local/nginx-cache-server/proxy-cache# ls 0
015ea98b87ad42eb41c536960df27720  3b0c7
[...]
```

Thank you !

Refference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_path